# mmenu menu item links doesent fire when i use together with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mmenu

I try make an mobile app with Cordova Hybrid platform. I just add a "mmenu.js" menu tool, and i need jquery mobile too. When i use together everythings looking good but mmenu links not working

(**just inside # tag for example**)

```
<a href="#section-two">test</a>
```

when i click this link nothing do, no console message and no error too. 
i have upload my code jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/f79m9co0/

i hope explain it my problem :( sorry my english...